# Using unobtrusive JavaScript, parameter isn't null, but its values are

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This was working when my JavaScript was in the same page as my cshtml file:

```
function SaveEntity() {
    // more code here
    alert(entity.FirstName);  // this shows that entity's properties have values
    $.post('/Home/Save', { entity: entity }, SaveComplete);
}
```

That code is now in a separate Index.js file. In my controller, the entity parameter isn't null, but all of its values are. Why would that happen now?

Controller signature:

```
public ActionResult Save(Entity entity)
{ // method here }
```

[image]

**Edit - Fiddler Screenshot**

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

This is the Entity class, generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Full Index.js, with the full SaveEntity() method:

```
var _currentEntities;

    $(function () {
        // Hide the ID column (column 1)
        $('#tableContacts').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [0] }
            ],
            "bLengthChange": false, // don't show the number of records to show per page
            "bFilter": false,  // don't show the search/filter box
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        });

        $('#waitImage').hide();
        // Show the letters of the alphabet, with a link to call GetEntries() for each of them.
        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            $('#headerAlphabet').append('<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"GetEntries(\''
                + String.fromCharCode(i) + '\')\">'
                + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</a> ');
        }
    });

            function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
                // code here
            }

            function EntriesReceived(entities) {
                // code here
            }

            function DisplayPerson(entityId) {
                // code here
            }

        function SaveEntity() {
            // Grab our entity
            var entity;
            for (var i = 0; i < _currentEntities.length; i++) {
                if (_currentEntities[i].EntityId == $('#txtEntityId').val()) {
                    entity = _currentEntities[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            entity.FirstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
            entity.LastName  = $('#txtLastName').val();
            entity.Address   = $('#txtAddress').val();
            entity.City      = $('#txtCity').val();
            entity.State     = $('#txtState').val();
            entity.ZipCode   = $('#txtZipCode').val();
            entity.Company   = $('#txtCompany').val();
            entity.Notes     = $('#txtNotes').val();

            alert(entity.FirstName);

            $.post('/Home/Save', { entity: entity }, SaveComplete);
        }

            function SaveComplete(saveStatus) {
                alert(saveStatus);
            }

            function CancelChanges() {
                alert('Cancel will be done here.');
            }
```

Comment: stupid question, but you do wrap that code in the `$(document).ready(function () {...`, right?

Comment: I do not. Is that necessary?

Comment: yes, because otherwise your page is not fully loaded and not all javascript has been instantiated, executed.

Comment: But that method doesn't get called until the page loads and the user makes changes and hits the save button. And the alert shows that `entity` does have its first name set. So, given that, I *still* need to wrap it?

Comment: well, not nessesarily, but it is hard to tell without seeing all of the  js for that page. you could try to wrap it, though, and test. the symptoms you describe look like somewhere javascript does not get fully loaded

Comment: I just posted the full Index.js code, with the method bodies removed for readability.

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't need to be wrapped in a document ready handler. Of course, I don't know about the code you _haven't_ shown...

Comment: @nnnnnn What more would be helpful to see?

Comment: id like to see the contents of your ready **$(function () {}** That's usually the smoking gun in a code move -- esp off page

Comment: I assume the GetEntries fires correctly?

Comment: @DaveA Indeed it does. All of those function fire. It's just that when SaveEntity() posts to the controller, the parameter's values are null.

Comment: I have done these kind of posts many times before. I always use .ajax so that I can set dataType: 'json' and traditional: true. In this case, I strongly suspect your entity should be converted into json. My only reservation is that it worked from server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when doing any kind of ajax submission, you want to look at the actual request in an Http debugger, like Fiddler.  You want to see if it's actually posting the values you think it is.  That will help you isolate whether the problem is in your javascript, or on the server.  Right now, you don't know.

See: [This](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-303210.html) and [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=JP1RbrxVti4C&pg=PT656&lpg=PT656&dq=using%20fiddler%20to%20debug%20ajax%20mvc&source=bl&ots=n_1V4nCC0S&sig=m54fUyvVQjIlwInVk8sP_QbXDb4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8nUxUauvKoL49QTDmIDABw&ved=0CG8Q6AEwBw)

Second, you should post your server side Entity definition.

EDIT:

This appears to be a problem with the way that jQuery serializes objects by default, which uses the bracket notation, which won't work with the default model binder.  You have to use the traditional: true parameter that Dave mentions.

More about that [Here](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/).  The following will solve your problem.  the `$.param` method when used with the true parameter will force traditional serialization.

```
$.post('/Home/Save', $.param(entity, true), SaveComplete);.
```

Comment: I'll take a look with fiddler now. And I posted the definition of the Entity class. Thanks.

Comment: When using Fiddler, on the Inspectors tab, in the Body section, I see the entity and all of its values. Since I'm not familiar with Fiddler, I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @BobHorn - post a screenshot of the fiddler inspector window that shows your post values.

Comment: I just posted it. +1 for the tips and the help, btw.

Comment: @BobHorn - that doesn't look right.. post the TextView rather than the WebForms view.

Comment: I just posted the TextView as well.

Comment: @BobHorn - yeah, those posted values do not look right at all.  They should not be using the brackets like that.  It should just be entity.FirstName, etc..  I'd suggest using Dave A's method, I've always found $.post to be goofy.

Comment: @MystereMan Okay, so then what? I could try what Dave suggested, but that seems like a bit of a work-around when it was working when the JavaScript was in the same file as the view.

Comment: @BobHorn - Are you sure you made no other changes?  Have you tried copying the code back into the page and seeing if it still works, unchanged?  Debugging is all about verifying what does work, often times we make tiny changes that cause problems, but we don't think we did anything that would cause it to fail, copying the code back (not just restoring your previous version) verifies that it is indeed a problem related to being external.

Comment: I can try that. I did make a change though. When I moved the JavaScript to its own page, this line no longer worked: `$.post('@Url.Action("Save")', entity, SaveComplete);` So I replaced it with `$.post('/Home/Save', { entity: entity }, SaveComplete);`

Comment: @BobHorn - Yes, because external javascript files are not parsed by the Razor engine, so it won't insert the value.  But, that would not be causing this problem.

Comment: I tried `$.ajaxSetup({ traditional: true });` and the entire entity was null in the controller method. Then I tried Dave's suggestion, and it worked. But I just don't get that. I've made `$.post()` calls before, so why isn't it working now. Grrrr...

Comment: @BobHorn - Well, based on the article I linked to.. if it was working before, it shouldn't have.  You must have been doing something to force traditional behavior.

Comment: @BobHorn - also, you can do this `$.post('/Home/Save', $.param(entity, true), SaveComplete);`.  using $.param with the true parameter forces traditional serialization.

Comment: @MystereMan That worked! And my `SaveComplete()` method was called with the return value from the controller. Can you update your answer to include that? I'll accept it then. And thank you for all of your help. Very nice of you.

Comment: @MystereMan This still works, even when removing `true`: `$.post('/Home/Save', $.param(entity), SaveComplete);` It has the added benefit of also sending `entity.Contacts` to the server (although the properties within those are null, but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate, b/c my answer doesn't address why this would work from View yet fail from js file. But I would use an ajax vs post call to be able to set json and traditional:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Save',
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    data: entity , //$.toJSON(data),
    success: function (data) {
          SaveComplete(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I can give that a shot. Your comment of `$.toJSON(Data)`, am I supposed to do that instead of just `data: entity`?

Comment: @BobHorn, no don't this is from other code i copied and pasted. most coding errors come from that trap ;) Just use data: entity. if that fails, we may try toJson. either way I'm convinced its an encoding problem.

Comment: +1 for the tip, even though I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Appreciate the help...

Comment: Your suggestion has `true` being passed to `SaveComplete()`. Is there a way to get back to the way I had it, so that `SaveComplete()` gets the result from the controller method?

Comment: @BobHorn, yes you can get data back from .ajax(). see my revised answer.