# MVC Controller Property Doesn't Recognize Parameter's Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling an MVC controller method and passing it an `Entity` object. Among other properties, `Entity` also has a `Contacts` property. With this approach, the controller gets the entity, and the right number of contacts within the entities, but all of the contacts' properties are null.

This is the original approach:

```
$.post('/Home/Save', $.param(entity), SaveComplete);
```

With the strongly-typed controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Entity entity)
```

This causes each `Entity.Contact` to have null properties:

[image]

And Fiddler shows that the contacts are passed to the server.

To get the controller to recognize the Contacts property of Entity, I have to do this:

JavaScript:

```
$.post('/Home/Save', { entityAsJson: JSON.stringify(entity) }, SaveComplete);
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Save(string entityAsJson)
{
    try
    {        
        Entity entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(entityAsJson);
        // more code here
    }
}
```

That's unfortunate, because now my controller takes a string instead of a strongly-typed entity. Is there a way to get the first option to work, or do I need to stringify the JSON?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie)  . The most upvoted ansver...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Which one of the three options, in that answer, are you suggesting? The original question doesn't show a collection within an object; only primitive properties on the main object.

Comment: You should not need the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Try simply doing json-serialization on the client, and leave the server as it was (IE: accepting an "Entity" object). Asp.NET MVC has it's own jsonvalueprovider. If that does not solve the problem, I remember reading sometime that there were some hoops you had to jump through to get MVC(3 I think) to play nice with arrays passed from the client.

Comment: I use `data: $('#form').serialize(),` to post model

Comment: Aha: Found it: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx. It's a bit dated, but I'm guessing if you conform to the specified format it should work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use strongly typed parameters in your controller actions and send data with ajax which gets bound correctly (including collection properties) you need to do the following things:

- use the `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` because `$.post` does not allow to configure the `contentType` option
- you need to send JSON. So you need to `JSON.stringfy` your data
- set the `contentType` to `"application/json"` because this tells ASP.NET MVC to use the correct model binder for JSON

So the following code should work with your original controller action:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/Home/Save', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: JSON.stringify(entity), 
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: SaveComplete 
});
```

Comment: @DaveA yeah, I know... I have answered this type of question multiple times but so far I was not able to find a good cannonical question/answer pair (not even inside the ones I've answered). So if you know a good one I will be happy to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @nemesv Dave is talking about his answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170512/279516. I didn't know it then, but his answer would have solved my original problem (that post - parameter's values are null), and my new problem (this post - collection's parameters *within* a parameter are null), although I wouldn't have known why. Your answer has a good explanation with it.

Comment: I'd say your implementation is better than mine. My jquery is still growing. For example, I like how you are passing a delegate to success method and having the data **implicitly** passed whereas I passed it **explicitly** and thereby less elegantly @nemesv

Answer (score 0):

In your case i don't know why are u making javascript post. If it's strongly type binding then just do the following:

(1) Wrap your controls, submit button under using block (Form).
(2) Call your action which should have your class name as an parameter.

e.g:

```
    Public Action Result (YourClassName model)
    {
          Your sample Code
    }
```

in model you will get whatever u have filled on your view...

Comment: Should this work for an object that has a collection property that is displayed using datatables?